# Solr fails with "missing required unique key id" error

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

There were a few questions on the similar topic but their resolutions do not seem to fit my case.

Env: Solr4.2.1, Tomcat 7

I am trying to index public movielens data, and started (as everybody) with the 'example' core. I have removed some fields from the schema not relevant to me, and added others to index movielens fields:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" /> 

<!-- fields for u.data in the grouplens data -->
<field name="user_number" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" /> 
<field name="item_number" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="rating" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<!-- end of fields for u.data in the grouplens data -->
<!-- fields for u.user in the grouplens data , userid is already specified above -->
<field name="age" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="gender" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="occupation" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="zipcode" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<!-- end of fields for u.user in the grouplens data -->
...
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

I am adding all fields in my Java indexer, including a generated 'id' field, I am also printing out each field I am adding , so from the console output below you can see that I indeed add the 'id' field, along with others... Yet, I am getting the following error:

```
May 5, 2013 9:43:06 AM org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil createClient
INFO: Creating new http client,   config:maxConnections=128&maxConnectionsPerHost=32&followRedirects=false
indexUserData() started for file: u.user
indexUserData() processing line: 1|24|M|technician|85711
adding field: [user_number, 1]
adding field: [id, u_user_1]
adding field: [age, 24]
adding field: [gender, M]
adding field: [occupation, technician]
adding field: [zipcode, 85711]
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:404)
```

Any idea what I am missing?
Thank you!
Marina

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

below your `<fields>` Tag in your Schema? You need to tell solr in the schema.xml, which field is going to be your unique key.

Comment: Yes, I do - sorry, I did not include that part into the schema fragment. I will update the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - it was a very embarrassing mistake... I had a loop over tokens while processing each line, and by mistake I had the statement to create new SolrInputDocument() inside the loop, not outside, so I was basically creating a new Document per field.... Now all works fine!